# Filled Array is Empty - Abort Trap:6

Tags: c, arrays, abort

I have one long array, and I'm trying to figure out how to split it up into two separate arrays, the second array has the right contents but the first is empty, I'm also getting an Abort Trap:6 and I'm not sure what that means.

I have an array called entireA, which looks something like this:

HELLO:WORLD, I want to put HELLO in a separate array (firstA) and WORLD in secondA. When I print first and second array at the end, secondA has the right contents but firstA doesn't event though I'm printing to check if the right characters are being passed over and they are -- but the firstA is still empty and I'm getting and abort trap i don't understand.

I've just started learning C, why is the first array empty and what does the error mean?

```
#define ARRSIZE 10000

char entireA[ARRSIZE] = "";
char firstA[ARRSIZE]  = "";
char secondA[ARRSIZE] = "";

strcpy(entireA,"HELLO:WORLD\n");

    int firstVar = 0;
    int entireVar = 0;
    while(entireA[entireVar] !=  ':') {
        if(entireA[entireVar] == ';') {
            break;
        }
        printf("%c \n",entireA[entireVar]);
            firstA[firstVar] = entireA[entireVar];
            firstVar++;
            entireVar++;
    }
    firstA[firstVar] = '\0';

    int secondVar = 0;
    entireVar++; //skip ':'
    while(entireA[entireVar] !=  '\n') {
            secondA[secondVar] = entireA[entireVar];
            secondVar++;
            entireVar++;
    }
    secondA[secondVar] = '\0';

printf("%s", firstA);
printf("%s", secondA);
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] if you want good feedback. Right now, we can't even see what you're printing ("I print first and second array at the end").

Comment: `entireA[entireVar] !=  ':'` - the array contains only `'\0` so this will loop forever and undefined behavior will happen. How is `ARRSIZE` defined?

Comment: If `entireA` doesn't contain à `\n`, it's going to end well. Please show à [MCVE], otherwise we can't tell you much more.

Comment: @KamilCuk there is a colon in the "test data". It would be **far clearer if we could see the code** though

Comment: I fixed up the example, it contains both ':' and '\n' now and shows what I'm printing.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] <<<- click here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP won't provide à minimal complete and verifyable example.

Comment: It seems that almost every abort trap 6 I see is caused by writing off the end of an array.  Or...  Is your env. such that you cannot get 30000 chars of data from the system?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

After execution, the variables have the following values:

```
entireA 0x02efcdb4 "HELLO:WORLD\n"  char[0x00002710]
entireVar   0x0000000b  int
firstA  0x02efa69c "HELLO"  char[0x00002710]
firstVar    0x00000005  int
secondA 0x02ef7f84 "WORLD"  char[0x00002710]
secondVar   0x00000005  int
```

Whatever your problem is, it's most likely something to do with your environment. I would suggest reducing the value of ARRSIZE to, say 80 characters, and seeing if that changes your results.